# VUE3 router-link load new page on middle not on top

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have a problem that when the user clicks on a specific product in the product category, a new page should load showing the details of that product (name, price, description, etc..).
The page loads but it scrolls in the middle of the page instead of loading at the top where you can see the header, menu and logo.

**Router**

```
export default createRouter({
    crollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        // always scroll to top
        return { top: 0 }
      },
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
    
})
```

**Link from category page**

```
<router-link :to="'product/'+product.url_slug" :title="product.name">
    <span>View product <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></span>
</router-link>
```

**Here is product detail page whis is scrolled.**

```
<template>
       <section id="product_top" class="store-category-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <h1 class="color-coffee">{{ product.data.name }}</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
         <section class="section-product-controls">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#opis">Overview</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Specification</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Downloads</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>               
            </div>
        </section>

<section class="product-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">                
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <p>{{ product.data.description }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <img :src="baseURL+'/slike/antidekubitni_dusek_slike/sace.png'" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

</template>
```

I try to see does exist some anchor link. No #anchor links have
I realy dont know how to slove this.

ANy idea? Thank

[image]

Comment: is it a typo? It should be `scrollBehavior`

Comment: No is not. Its copy/paste mistake here. I check.

Answer (score 0):

I might got a similar problem, only solution for me was following snippet

```
// Prevent down scrolling/scroll memorisation
if (history.scrollRestoration) {
    history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/scrollRestoration

I put that in my main.ts file
might fix your problem, but it will disable the autoscrolling feature globally for the whole vue app. (but you can toggle it)

Comment: I slove when i change position of scrollBehavior with history property and work. I dont try this but i will save it for next time. Thanks for solution.